# Why am I getting hits to pages with ?fb_xd_fragment=

Tags: facebook, analytics, blogger

I have added a Facebook like box and like buttons on [my blog](http://pedazosdecarbono.blogspot.com/) and, recently, I've been seeing on analytics a lot of hits to pages ending with `?fb_xd_fragment=`.

I've found a [related thread](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=60571) on the Facebook Forums which, worryingly, mentions that for some weird reason IE8 users are being redirected to a blank page! This is terrible, am I losing a significant portion of my visitors because when they try to visit my blog they're greeted by a blank page? (I don't have at hand a Windows computer with IE8 to check)

Also on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955012/facebook-javascript-sdk-fb-xd-fragment) on SO, it is suggested to add `xmlns:fb="facebook.com/2008/fbml"` to the main `html` tag (which I've done just now), and to add a `channel.html` file. But I can't do the later, because my blog is hosted on blogger and I can't upload html files.

So my question is twofold:

1. even after adding the `xmlns:fb`, could this still be an issue that affects IE8 visitors
2. how should I go about to fix it for my blog on blogger?

Comment: I tried loading http://pedazosdecarbono.blogspot.com/?fb_xd_fragment=test and I got a blank page in both IE9 *and* Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Facebook Platform bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9777) (marked "WontFix") a workaround seems to be to add the following to your pages:

From [comment 14](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9777#c14):

```
<!-- Correct fb_xd_fragment Bug Start --> 
<script> 
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.display='block';
</script> 
<!-- Correct fb_xd_fragment Bug End -->
```

Alternatively, you could look into implementing the solution proposed by [comment 66](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9777#c66), however as you're hosted on Blogspot I don't think that solution is open to you, as it requires the creation of an additional file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

on a page linked ([this one](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9777)) on the thread you linked it said:

> This Javascript to escape being framed on the page is the source of
>   the problem:
>
> 0) { parent.location.href =
>   location.href; }
>       -->
>
> When I remove that, Internet Explorer works.
>
> The page works fine in both Firefox and Chrome with that code included
>   on the page.

I unfortunately also can not reproduce the problem, but i hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this [fix](http://dorkage.net/blog/2011/01/18/fb_xd_fragment-facebook-bugfix/)

Where you have your FB.init, add a channelUrl parameter as follows:

```
FB.init({appId: appId, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, channelUrl: 'http://example.com/channel.html'});  
// ^ channel URL above used to workaround fb_xd_fragment bug
```

Next implement a special static channel page. On that page include the javascript for the Facebook connect as follows:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this occurring on one of my sites using AddThis - and it affects ALL browsers, not just Internet Explorer. Haven't figured out exactly how or why it happens but the Facebook frame manages to set the parent's `<html>` element to `display: none`.

There is a simple workaround though - just add this to your stylesheet:

```
html { 
    display: block !important;
}
```

That overrides the inline style and stops the page disappearing.